# Initiate command prompt from tex-file

Tags: compiling

Is there something one can put into a tex-file that makes the compiler prompt for further commands when it gets to it?

What I want to do is load polyglossia, set the language, and then do \showhyphens{with whatever words whose standard hyphenation I want to check} from the prompt.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have an interactive session with (Xe)TeX, you need to launch it from a terminal.

Prepare the following file, calling it `testhyphens.tex` (or whatever name you prefer):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra} % for `\showhyphens`

\setmainlanguage{italian} % or whatever language

\begin{document} % this selects the main language
```

Now from a terminal launch

```
xelatex testhyphens
```

The interpreter will stop with a `*` prompt, at which you can specify any TeX input, for instance

```
*\showhyphens{precipitevolissimevolmente}
```

(that's the longest word in Italian literature, barring chemical compound names) and hit the return key. This will output

```
*\showhyphens{precipitevolissimevolmente}

*********************** \showhyphens: ***********************

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 0
 \EU1/lmr/m/n/10 pre-ci-pi-te-vo-lis-si-me-vol-men-te

*************************************************************


*
```

with a new `*` prompt. You can end the session by typing `\stop` and hitting the return key.

The `xltxtra` package is needed in order to modify the stock definition of `\showhyphens` that doesn't work when an OpenType font is the current font (it is, in this case, because `polyglossia` loads `fontspec` that sets Latin Modern as default font, in its OpenType version).

Comment: It's probably easiest to do an interactive session at the terminal, but some editors do also give you access to the prompt.

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, TeXShop and TeXworks do.